# How to do YTD, MTD calculations based on the Today()

Tags: reporting-services

I am very new to SSRS, I have below scenario.

I have to calculate measures for YTD, MTD, Last 7 Days and Previous day based on the `today()`.  I need to use these YTD, MTD, Last 7 days and Previous day variables in the calculations while writing the IIF syntax

For example:

```vb
sum(IIF(Year="this year is Year to Date", value, sales)

sum(IIF(CreatedDate="the last 30days values ",sales)
```

Can any one please tell me how to achieve this

Thanks

Comment: Please can you clarify your pseudo-code above as to what you're actually trying to achieve.  What is the desired end result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **YEAR** function to get the year of a date field. An **IIF** statement is used to evaluate an expression (in your case if the date is within the current year) then the desired result if the expression is true then the result if false. So your YTD formula could look like:

```
=SUM(IIF(YEAR(Fields!YourDateField.Value) = Year(TODAY()), Fields!Sales.Value, 0)
```

This reads: The sum of (if the year = current year then Sales else 0).

The last 30 days is similar but you would use the **DATEADD** function to figure what the date was 30 days ago:

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!YourDateField.Value >= DATEADD("d", -30, TODAY()), Fields!Sales.Value, 0)
```

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337194(v=sql.100).aspx

Comment: Thank you so much Hannover Fist